# Suppress Warnings in Simpletest JUnit XML output in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, drupal-7, simpletest

I am working with a Drupal 7 multisite installation that is inside a Vagrant created VM. I am using Jenkins to run Simpletests on a few sites in this environment.

The output of these tests is in JUnit XML and it is read by Jenkins. The problem that I am having is that the output contains some php warnings that are irrelevant to the outcome of the tests, yet the test is marked as a failure due to these warnings.

An example of a notice:

```
`exception: [Notice] Array to string conversion [theme.inc:129]`
```

The above "notice" is marked as a failed test.

I would like to suppress these warnings and notices so the tests only fail on errors or actual failed tests.

Here is a full output of one test:

```
Error Message

Number of unexpected errors: 2

Stacktrace

exception: [Notice] Array to string conversion [theme.inc:129]
exception: [Notice] Array to string conversion [theme.inc:129]

Standard Output

exception: [Notice] Array to string conversion [theme.inc:129]
exception: [Notice] Array to string conversion [theme.inc:129]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress these warnings and notices by adding:
`error_reporting(E_ERROR);`
To the top of the the global settings file.
All tests passed!